# How to wait for WebSocket STOMP messages in Cypress.io

Tags: websocket, stomp, cypress

In one of my tests I want to wait for WebSocket STOMP messages. Is this possible with Cypress.io?

Answer (score 3):

If the websocket you'd like to access is being established by your application, you could follow this basic process:

1. Obtain a reference to the `WebSocket` instance from inside your test.
2. Attach an event listener to the `WebSocket`.
3. Return a [Cypress Promise](https://docs.cypress.io/api/utilities/promise.html#Syntax) that is resolved when your `WebSocket` receives the message.

This is a bit difficult for me to test out, absent a working application, but something like this should work:

**In your application code:**

```js
// assuming you're using stomp-websocket: https://github.com/jmesnil/stomp-websocket

const Stomp = require('stompjs');

// bunch of app code here...

const client = Stomp.client(url);
if (window.Cypress) {
  // running inside of a Cypress test, so expose this websocket globally
  // so that the tests can access it
  window.stompClient = client
}
```

**In your Cypress test code:**

```js
cy.window()         // yields Window of application under test
.its('stompClient') // will automatically retry until `window.stompClient` exists
.then(stompClient => {
  // Cypress will wait for this Promise to resolve before continuing
  return new Cypress.Promise(resolve => {
    const onReceive = () => {
      subscription.unsubscribe()  // clean up our subscription
      resolve()                   // resolve so Cypress continues
    }
    // create a new subscription on the stompClient
    const subscription = stompClient.subscribe("/something/you're/waiting/for", onReceive)
  })
})
```

Comment: What if the implementation code is out of my control - can I still intercept *websocket* messages in my *Cypress* tests (similarly to how `cy.intercept(uri)`)?