# Sometimes cypress seems to block the update of the DOM when getting new information via a websocket call

Tags: websocket, cypress

I am open a page via

`cy.visit('https://localhost:9099/test')`

The page automatically set up a websokcet to the server and send some "questions" which are answered. When answered the javascript code in the page updates the DOM/page.

The problem I have is that the DOM/page is not always updated and the

`cy.get('#ID', {timeout:40000})`

fails.

Does cypress interfere with the page code in some way? I have executed the same test with Selenium during several years and the page always behave then.

Answer (score 0):

Cypress tries to wait for the page to finish loading before executing the commands, so perhaps the websocket interaction goes un-noticed in the page-loaded check.

If you know the last websocket message, you could await it.

Here's an example [How to wait for WebSocket STOMP messages in Cypress.io](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55522388)

**application**

```js
// assuming you're using stomp-websocket: https://github.com/jmesnil/stomp-websocket

const Stomp = require('stompjs');

// bunch of app code here...

const client = Stomp.client(url);
if (window.Cypress) {
  // running inside of a Cypress test, so expose this websocket globally
  // so that the tests can access it
  window.stompClient = client
}
```

**test**

```js
cy.window()         // yields Window of application under test
.its('stompClient') // will automatically retry until `window.stompClient` exists
.then(stompClient => {
  // Cypress will wait for this Promise to resolve before continuing
  return new Cypress.Promise(resolve => {
    const onReceive = () => {
      subscription.unsubscribe()  // clean up our subscription
      resolve()                   // resolve so Cypress continues
    }
    // create a new subscription on the stompClient
    const subscription = stompClient.subscribe("/something/you're/waiting/for", onReceive)
  })
})
```